Why my CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' is empty
My file .aspx
<td rowspan="2" class="btn" >
    <asp:HiddenField id="hdnID" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnAnswer" runat="server" Text="Answer" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="answer-button" CommandName="OpenPage" 
  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CausesValidation="false" />
</td>

I check my hdnID has value ='2'. But in the code =''.
My file .cs
protected void listView_ItemCommad(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "OpenPage")
    {
        string id = (e.CommandArgument).ToString();
        
        Response.Redirect("GoIkenHenshuuGamen.aspx?id=" + id);
    }
}


Remove the viewstate = false-

I did something like that once and did this:
int ID = int.Parse(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandArgument);

Try that, changing LinkButton to Button. Remove int.Parse too.
